# Convert a type (int, float etc) to `T` [go1.18]

Tags: go, generics

***Scenario***:
Go 1.18 that support generics

***Problem***:
Unable to convert a number into generics.

***Explanation***:
I'm trying to port my `general purpose` library to support generics. I'm dealing with number cast error.

I've defined a package that contains all the number types as following:

```golang
package types

type Number interface {
    int | int8 | int16 | int32 | int64 | uint | uint8 | uint16 | uint32 | uint64 | uintptr | float32 | float64
}
```

I've no particular problem to deal with generics. The only thing that I've not understood is:
How to convert a defined type (like `int`) to a generic?

*Let's assume the following example:*

```golang
// FindIndexValue is delegated to retrieve the index of the given value into the input array.
func FindIndexValue[T types.Number](array []T, value T) []T {
    var indexs []T
    for i := range array {
        if array[i] == value {
            indexs = append(indexs, i)
        }
    }
    return indexs
}
```

In the above snippet, the error is located in the line:

```golang
 ...
 for i := range array {
   ...
}
```

This because the `range` builtin iterate the array and return the index (`int`) of the given position.

The question is:
***How can I convert the defined type (`int` in this case) to the generic `T`?***
Error:
`cannot use i (variable of type int) as type T in argument to append`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You convert a value to a parameter type as you would normally do.

From the proposal [Type conversions](https://go.googlesource.com/proposal/+/refs/heads/master/design/43651-type-parameters.md#type-conversions):

> In a function with two type parameters `From` and `To`, a value of type `From` may be converted to a value of type `To` if **all the types in the type set of From's constraint can be converted to all the types in the type set of To's constraint.**

In this case you don't really have a `From` because it is the slice index `int`; the destination type would be `T` (even though this is probably not what you want, see below why). Of course `int` can be converted to `T`'s type set due to it including only numerical types (albeit with [truncation or loss of precision](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Conversions) in case of `int8` or `float64`!)

```
indexs = append(indexs, T(i))
```

however your program is declaring the slice of indices as `[]T`, which means that instantiating your generic function as:

```
is := FindIndexValue([]float64{1,5,7,9}, float64(9))
```

will yield a result of type `[]float64`. Since the returned values are slice indices, which are always `int`, this doesn't make a lot of sense.

Better would be to return simply `[]int`:

```
func FindIndexValue[T Number](array []T, value T) []int {
    var indices []int
    for i := range array {
        // match on the generically typed slice item
        if array[i] == value {
            // store slice indices as ints
            indices = append(indexs, i)
        }
    }
    return indices
}
```

Playground: https://gotipplay.golang.org/p/EykXppG2qJa

Answer (score 5):

The index is always integer type (`int`) regardless of the element type of the slice. So result type should be `[]int`.

Why would you want it to be `[]T`? If `T` is `uint8` and the passed slice contains more than 256 elements, you couldn't even return the proper indices.

```
func FindIndexValue[T types.Number](array []T, value T) []int {
    var indices []int
    for i, v := range array {
        if v == value {
            indices = append(indices, i)
        }
    }
    return indices
}
```